# How can you make a function that takes as a parameter an arbitrary function pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I am trying to do the following, and I am not even sure if it's possible.

I want a function that takes in an arbitrary function pointer  to pass it to a different function (I am aware this is a code smell, good software engineering practices are not what I want to discuss right now).

In other words what I am looking for would look like:

```
void method1(arbitraty pointer p)
{
    method2(p);
}
```

I am not sure if there is a way to declare arbitrary function pointers (the return value is guaranteed to be void but the parameters are arbitrary, both in number and type)

Comment: I guess you can pass a void pointer and cast it, but if you are planning on calling the function from inside method2, I would definitely complain about code smell - functions with different numbers of parameters cannot be interchanged - the changes they make to the stack pointer are baked into the generated code, and so you will smash your stack if you cast e.g. a 2-parameter function pointer to a 1-parameter function pointer and call it.  I like the "templates" answer in the above comment btw - you should look into that.  There are variadic templates too, maybe those will work.

Comment: What are you planning to do with that pointer inside method2?

Comment: The full sotry is I am trying to make a wrapper class for GLFW windows for future projects. I am trying to set each GLFW callback function through this method

The way around so far has been abusing the fact that most GLW callback function have different signatures and just dup[licate the code per each callback funciton

Comment: The full story is fine and dandy but the important question is *What are you planning to do with that pointer inside method2?* Show the line of code that uses it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use template and use SFINAE to enable it only if the type deduced is a function pointer type:

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_function<T>::value, int> = 0>
void method1(T* p)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be considered over-engineering by some, but you could try the following:

Create an enum of each callback that you are interested in:

```
enum GlfwCallback {
    KeyCallback,
    FramebufferSizeCallback,
    // etc.
};
```

Then create a type family that associates each of these with the corresponding function pointer type.  Do this by creating a template struct and repeatedly specializing it:

```
template<GflwCallback callback>
struct GlfwCallbackType {};

template<>
struct GlfwCallbackType<KeyCallback> {
    using CallbackType = GLFWkeyfun;
    // or
    using CallbackType = void(*)(GLFWwindow *, int, int, int, int);
};

template<>
struct GlfwCallbackType<FramebufferSizeCallback> {
    using CallbackType =  GLFWframebuffersizefun;
};

// etc.
```

Then you can write

```
template<GlfwCallback callback>
void method1(GlfwCallbackType<callback>::CallbackType p) {
    // do something with p
    method2<callback>(p);
};
```

Also, note that you can add other types and even static functions and data members to your "type family" as needed by your application.

Comment: At this point I feel I might as well stick with abusing signatures : P

Answer (score 1):

A possibility to do what you want, but in a nice, type-safe fashion, would be the use of functors, i.e. classes that define an overloading for the `operator()`.
Since a functor is a class, you could set the arguments as data memebers, and move the implementation/calling of the functions that you want to pass as arbitrary pointers into the operator() method, where you can have access to all the parameters through the `this` pointer.

Furthermore, you can define a hierarchy of functors, each one with specialized parameters and implementations, so you can modify the signature of method2 like the following:

```
method2(BaseFunctor* myfunctor) {
   if (myfunctor) 
      (*myfucntor)();
}
```

and setup the right type of functor object in the calling context.

Also check out lambdas (c++11), that are basically a shortcut to functors definition.